# "Log out" claims to be local, but logs out everywhere

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, logout

I'm usually logged in to Super User from three different devices (home PCs and phone). Sometimes, I log in using my school's computer, post something, then log out from that computer. However, even though the page says "Clicking Log Out will clear all local credentials in your browser", it logs me out of *everywhere* – all four devices. This quickly becomes annoying.

Is this a bug or 'feature'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't recall off hand when this change happened, but yes it's by design.

Too many people were getting confused by our old logout scheme, which could:

- log you out of the local machine
- (optionally) log you out of all machines
- clear your global login credentials
- (potentially) log you out of openid.stackexchange.com

It sort of grew organically into a nightmare, really, with shades of "Vista Shutdown Menu" in there.

So now logout just does as much of the above as possible, all the time.

However, you're right the copy is a bit off there (especially if you're familiar with the old scheme); it will be changed in the next build.

Comment: ...where "clear your global login credentials" implied one could no longer log in on other sites without entering any credentials—but if already logged in, one would not be logged out. (If I recall correctly.)

Comment: @Arjan - yeah... I simplified a bit, there was a way to logout & clear global login; there was also a way to just clear global login.