# Log Out Everywhere, missing?

Tags: discussion, support, logout

I am trying to **really** log out of Stack Overflow. If I just go through the normal logout process it still leaves me logged in at [openid.stackexchange.com](http://openid.stackexchange.com). This will allow login without password on next attempt, which I **don't want**.

[**This question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73686) references the <kbd>Log Out Everywhere</kbd> button, which looks promising, but seems nowhere to be found.

Comment: Is there a different logout option for openid.stackexchange? I'm logged *in* to stack exchange via that openid but I'm not logged in to openid.stackexchange

Comment: Weird, logging out of UX didn't log me out of Cog Sci just now, maybe the lougout is broken? It used to log out all sites on all devices just recently which is what it should do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the log out scheme was cleaned up; "Log out" now logs you out everywhere, according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108161/140890.

However, that answer seems to imply that you'd also be logged out of http://openid.stackexchange.com/ which is clearly not the case for you, so that could either be bug or perhaps even by design.