# Login/Logout with single Stack Exchange account

Tags: support, login, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add “network wide logout” functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86920/add-network-wide-logout-functionality)

I've tried it on different Stack Exchange sites. There are individual sessions maintained for each site. Logging in/out on one site doesn't reflect on the other. I have to manually log in/out on the other. It would be better to have single login/logout. Because it's hard to remember all the sites that I've logged in especially when at work. Or is it already available in Stack Exchange, and I didn't notice?

I tried logging out from stackoverflow.com but I'm still logged in in meta.stackoverflow.com. Do I have to change any setting to log out all the sessions?

Comment: Logging out should already be network wide [shouldn't it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107498/log-out-claims-to-be-local-but-logs-out-everywhere/108161#108161)

Comment: Is this a 'You guys should do this' or a legitimate question?

Comment: @Bart Sorry for the late reply. I tried logging out from stackoverflow.com but I'm still logged in in meta.stackoverflow.com. Do I have to change any setting to log out all the sessions?

Comment: Hmm, don't know. I've edited that info into your question to give it a bump.

Comment: @Bart that other question is about logging out from all devices, not all sites. It's still per site as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Bart Thanks. If SO doesn't have it already, they should consider it a.s.a.p. Keeping track of all the Stack Exchange logins is really difficult. If SO has it already, hope somebody might help soon.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Okay. So I see this has been a discussion for a long. But SE seems to have no update/info on this.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ah, thanks for that info. Never log out myself. :)

Comment: @Rocky the owners and developers of Stack Exchange are already paying great attention to features suggested here and to discussions, much more than on any other site. However with hundreds of requests, lots of them stay inactive and don't get real attention.

Comment: Yeah I know. This is one of the best sites I use. But my point is many users are expecting for this feature. So it would be better if it's implemented as early as possible. I hope there'll be an update soon. May be they're working on it.