# Can we have a "log out on this computer only" button?

Tags: feature-request, login, logout, session

While it's great to have the ability to clear all session cookies for all devices, I'd like the ability to log out on one computer only, and not come home to have to relogin on all of my devices. It can really be a pain.

Is there a technical reason we don't have this, or why don't we?

Comment: Yes, please. Sometimes I like to test other browsers for features temporarily, that I particularly don't want my account logged in on, and it gets quite frustrating.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Exactly! And I have SE logged in on all my mobile devices (iPad), and because I like to upvote answers from the newsletter in the Gmail app, I have to resignin in Gmail, browser, mobile chrome, and everywhere else. It's a pain. I'm surprised no one's asked for this before.

Comment: And to complement this feature, I'd like an ability to log out other sessions remotely.

Comment: @J.Steen: Also, perfect. I just want this in addition.

Comment: I think that this feature is considered overcomplicated. The login system [used to have such features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107498/238706). From how I guess it works, you have always just one global session (stored on server), to which you can connect from multiple browsers (possibly on different devices; connection info is stored locally). If you delete the session, all your connections are invalid, you get logged out everywhere. If you delete just one connection, you get logged out in the browser; but this must be done from the browser as the connection is stored locally.