# Please, don't force me to log-out on all devices

Tags: support, login, logout, session

I logged in on two systems, ie, office system and home. If I logged out of any one of the system means it won't get logged out , it asked me that I should log out on all devices.

Then I have to re log in to the system which I require. It is a nice feature to have logout on all devices.

This is happen for different browsers of same system too. This feature might not be seen for Gmail or Facebook or yahoo. and yes, StackOverflow is not a social networking.

I'm not asking for a new feature-request here. since, it's already [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172092/can-we-have-a-log-out-on-this-computer-only-button).

What is the reason for forcing a user to log-out on all devices?

What is the drawback on logging out a single system or browser?