# Does the log-out from all the Stack Exchange sites still exists?

Tags: support, login, openid

There is already a question about this, *[Log out of all Stack Exchange sites with linked account simultaneously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73686)*, but unfortunately it hasn't been updated, like also this one, *[Can we have a "log out on this computer only" button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172092)*.

Currently the log-out page says:

Clicking *Log Out* will clear our cookies and log you out of Stack Overflow on all devices.

If you're on a shared computer, remember to log out of your OpenID provider (Facebook, Google, Stack Exchange, etc.) as well.

But still if I log out of meta, and the open stackoverflox, I am logged in again. Do I have to log out from my email (that I use for OpenID), and then login again to it for, ehm, checking my email?

Comment: "stackoverflox"?